# networking in virtualization

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I have a `redhat9` as guest and a `fedora18` as host. the guest is connected to network but I'm not sure through `bridge` or `nat`. I just know that other machines can't ssh or ping it. because they are not in the same range of ips. I don't know much about networking may you describe me 
how should I change the network setting so that the guest has he same range of ip as host and the other machines?
If it matters I work with `xen` as hypervisor and `virt manager` and I used the default settings while creating the guest.
I'll appreciate if you link me to a step by step manual to first understand the needings and then setting up them. I thought I should set up a bridge and I just edited some configuration files in host but it caused disconnecting even internet!

Comment: You need to configure your network to be bridged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to set up a bridge.  Xen drivers create a virtual network adapter in dom0 (host) that you bridge to your physical adapter. Try:

```
# brctl addbr xenbr0
# brctl addif xenbr0 eth0
# brctl addif xenbr0 vif1.0
# dhclient eth0 -r
# dhclient xenbr0
```

This should get an IP address for the bridge and the guest should be able to use it to DHCP its own IP address.  Fill in the correct adapter names instead of eth0 and vif1.0